# Assign a custom key to a session in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller, session-state

I'm building a .NET 6 Core MVC Application In which I want to create a session whose key is "customer".
And then I want to check on each page whether that session is valid or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.1st Store your key value in a session.**

```
Session["Key"]="customer"
```

**.2nd Check your session value in another page if the value is valid or not.**

```
if(Session["Key"].ToString()=="customer")
{
//valid action
}
else
{
//invalid action
}
```